# Ionic integration with google api's (like google Drive) and also authorize with google

Tags: google-drive-api, ionic-framework, google-authentication

Recently I stuck into an issue where I wanted to authorize my ionic application with Google as well as I also integrate Google drive into my application. After struggling couple of days I got to a  solution and wrote my own [Ionic-google-drive-integration](https://github.com/Raza-Dar/ionic-google-drive)  demo project. It has a complete step-by-step guide directions.